# turning a string into a variable (bad operand type for unary +: 'str')

Tags: python

Why do I keep receiving this error? I guess the raw_input() is being read as an input() and it cannot see the users input as a string. I do not know how I can change this so that it may work. And, no, the question: "Python 2.7 getting user input and manipulating as string without quotations" does not answer my question.

```
options = ["An animal", "A food", "A fruit", "A number", "A superhero name", "A country", "A dessert", "A year"]
#"options" become variables
for i in options:
    if i[0:3] == "An ":
        exec("%s = %s" % (i[3::], raw_input("Enter " + i + " ")))
    else:
        exec("%s = %s" % (i[2::], raw_input("Enter " + i + " ")))
```

I keep recieving this error:

```
NameError: name 'input' is not defined
```

Comment: It's probably pointing at this part: `raw_input("Enter ", + i + " ")`. Do you see what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Penguin: Assign `raw_input("Enter ", + i + " ")` to a variable first and then place the variable where `raw_input` is now. So: `a = raw_input("Enter ", + i + " ")`, and then `exec("%s = %s" % (i[3::], a)`.

Comment: I see that this is the second question about this code that you've asked in an hour, and both are about topics already answered on this site. Please take some more time to research your questions before asking here. Try googling the exception name with "site:stackoverflow.com" to see other SO answers.

Comment: I searched around, but I couldn't find any answers that helped with my problem specifically. I tried a bunch of links. The link you attached is a similar problem, but that user's problem was that he used input() rather than raw_input(). I am already using raw_input().

Comment: Look at the answers though. They have perfectly good examples of how to use `raw_input`. There are also plenty of other questions about string concatenation and variable substitution as well. Being able to extrapolate from similar examples and come up with an original solution is an important skill for programmers - you won't always be able to find verbatim code examples. When you can't do that, your question should include references to the other sources you consulted and describe why those solutions didn't work for you.

Comment: Even if you could get this working as you expect, what do you expect to happen when processing "A superhero name"?

Comment: I would change it to "a superhero".

Comment: But you aren't.  Furthermore, let's say you type in `dog` for the first `raw_input` call.  You're then doing `exec("animal = dog")`.  If you typed `animal = dog` directly into a Python interpreter, what will happen?

Comment: @skrrgwasme This isn't really a `raw_input` question.  It's actually an `exec` question.

Comment: @jamesdlin I think it's a few different questions in one: "How to I store user input into a variable?" "How do I substitute a variable into a string?" "How do I handle an 'XXX is not defined' exception?" Though after the edit and comments, I agree that it wasn't the best dupe target, to choose. I'm going to retract that vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information, but my psychic powers tell me that when you were prompted with "Enter an animal ", you typed `input`.

Try to mentally walk through what your code is doing, particularly when you get to:

```
exec("%s = %s" % (i[3::], raw_input("Enter " + i + " ")))
```

So for the first iteration through the loop, this becomes:

```
exec("%s = %s" % ("animal", "input"))
```

Then when the substitution happens:

```
exec("animal = input")
```

Which is equivalent to typing:

```
animal = input
```

directly into the Python interpreter.  `input` isn't defined, so you get:

```
NameError: name 'input' is not defined
```

You probably meant to surround the right-hand side with quotes to treat it as a string when executed:

```
 exec("%s = '%s'" % ("animal", "input")) # Note that this is unsafe.  See the note below.
```

All that being said, I feel obligated to say that this code is incredibly brittle.  When the loop iterates to "A superhero name", it will also break because `superhero name` isn't a valid identifier.  You instead probably should split the string on spaces and perhaps take the second word, or just replace all spaces with, say, underscores.  Additionally, you will need to sanitize user input so that a user can't escape by supplying quotes in the input. (Or even better would be to avoid using `exec` with user input entirely.  Do you really need variable names?  Why not just use a Python dictionary mapping the prompted strings to the input strings?)